# How to set background.png to be background of progress bar and progress to stretch and be part which is filling to max?

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I have progress bar and I have two images `background.png` and `progress.png`.
How to set background.png to be background of progress bar and progress to stretch and be part which is filling to max ?

I have tried like `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are trying put your own image in **ProgressBar** then you should create custom **ProgressBar** which will help you to set your own image as background and progress image.

Here, I'm giving you a way how to do the custom **ProgressBar**.  Create a XML to handle **background.png** as proress bar's background and **progress.png** as proress bar's progress indicator with **layer-list** attribute...named the XML as **progressbar.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        <!--setting background.png as background of proressbar-->
        android:drawable="@drawable/background"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        <!--setting progress.png as progress drawable of proressbar-->
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Create custom **ProgressBar** named **CustomProgressBar** which **extends ProgressBar**.
**CustomProgressBar.java**

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // update the size of the progress bar and overlay
        updateProgressBar();

        // paint the changes to the canvas
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) {
        super.setProgress(progress);

        // the setProgress super will not change the details of the progress bar
        // anymore so we need to force an update to redraw the progress bar
        invalidate();
    }

    private float getScale(int progress) {
        float scale = getMax() > 0 ? (float) progress / (float) getMax() : 0;

        return scale;
    }

    private void updateProgressBar() {
        Drawable progressDrawable = getProgressDrawable();

        if (progressDrawable != null && progressDrawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
            LayerDrawable d = (LayerDrawable) progressDrawable;

            final float scale = getScale(getProgress());

            // get the progress bar and update it's size
            Drawable progressBar = d.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progress);

            final int width = d.getBounds().right - d.getBounds().left;

            if (progressBar != null) {
                Rect progressBarBounds = progressBar.getBounds();
                progressBarBounds.right = progressBarBounds.left + (int) (width * scale + 0.5f);
                progressBar.setBounds(progressBarBounds);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Create a Style attribute for the custom progress bar in **styles.xml**...

```
<resources>

    <style name="Widget"></style>

    <style name="Widget.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">true</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateBehavior">repeat</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">3500</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.ProgressBar.RegularProgressBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progressbar</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">1dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">10dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Add the custom **CustomProgressBar** into your XML. Suppose, you put the **CustomProgressBar.java** file in **com.widgets.custom** package...then xml for progress bar will be...

```
<com.widgets.custom.CustomProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/regularprogressbar"
    style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.RegularProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" />
```

In your Activity class initialize the custom progress bar and use as your need. But I'm giving **demo Activity class** for better understanding...

```
public class ProgressBarActivity extends Activity {

    private SaundProgressBar mRegularProgressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mRegularProgressBar = (SaundProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.regularprogressbar);

        new UpdateBarTask().execute();
    }

    private class UpdateBarTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int max = mRegularProgressBar.getMax();
            for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
                try {
                    // update every second
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }

                publishProgress(i);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            mRegularProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe for this you need to set a full style for the `android:progressBarStyleHorizontal`
You can see all of the values needed if you go to http://android-holo-colors.com/ and just download a theme that sets the progress bar

Comment: I set to android:progressBarStyleHorizontal but how to change default images to mine

Comment: you should be able to set the images to yours through the style that is generated from that site. Once you set that attribute to be your style, you'll create a style, whose parent is android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal. The necessary attributes are given to you within the styles and themes files in the values dir